# Joomla - one admin panel for multi sites

Tags: joomla3.0, administrator

I was trying to find some possible solutions to manage one administration panel for multi domains, but didn't find anything relevant.

Does anybody know if it is possible in Joomla 3.x? And if yes could somebody provide any possible solution, especially not commercial one?

Many thanks !

Comment: This is probably best asked over on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use a Joomla extension that provides multi sites feature. 
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites

I prefer this [Joomla multi sites extension](http://codingmall.com/products-mainmenu-8/178-joomla-multi-sites-extension) by the way: